# Calculate top-level of hierarchy path?

Tags: sql, oracle, parent-child, hierarchical-data, maximo

I have a `classstructure` table:

```
create table classstructure (classstructureid number(8,0), classificationid varchar2(25), parent number(8,0));

insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1001, 'FLEET', null);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1002, 'LIGHTDUTYVEHICLE', 1001);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1004, 'MEDIUMDUTYVEHICLE', 1001);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1022, 'ACTIVETRANSPORTATION', null);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1023, 'FACILITYWALKWAY', 1022);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1024, 'TRAIL', 1022);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1085, 'SIDEWALK', 1022);
insert into classstructure(classstructureid, classificationid, parent) values(1091, 'SDWRAMP', 1085);
commit;

select * from classstructure;

CLASSSTRUCTUREID CLASSIFICATIONID              PARENT
---------------- ------------------------- ----------
            1001 FLEET                               
            1002 LIGHTDUTYVEHICLE                1001
            1004 MEDIUMDUTYVEHICLE               1001

            1022 ACTIVETRANSPORTATION                
            1023 FACILITYWALKWAY                 1022
            1024 TRAIL                           1022
            1085 SIDEWALK                        1022
            1091 SDWRAMP                         1085
```

I would like to calculate the top level of each row's hierarchy path:

```
CLASSSTRUCTUREID TOP LEVEL
---------------- ---------
1001             FLEET
1002             FLEET
1004             FLEET

1022             ACTIVETRANSPORTATION
1023             ACTIVETRANSPORTATION
1024             ACTIVETRANSPORTATION
1085             ACTIVETRANSPORTATION
1091             ACTIVETRANSPORTATION
```

Is it possible to do this with Oracle 18c SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [hierarchical query](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Queries.html#GUID-0118DF1D-B9A9-41EB-8556-C6E7D6A5A84E), with [`connect_by_root`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Query-Operators.html#GUID-875C8985-4AEF-4DF1-BA23-3CDF5BCBCD8E):

```
select classstructureid, connect_by_root(classificationid)
from classstructure
connect by parent = prior classstructureid
start with parent is null;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c819cfc2e6713b51dc323f5c16a2fa11)